# Is there equivalent of Power Apps Approvals connector in Logic Apps?

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-logic-apps, powerapps, power-automate

I am trying to create a Microsoft Teams Approval workflow using Logic Apps but the Approvals connector is not available there. Is there either equivalent or different way to create such MS Teams workflow using Logic Apps?

[image]

Comment: Hi @Georgi Yankov, We are checking internally on this with engineering team and will update you soon.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, Approvals connector is not available for flow creations using Logic Apps. You can raise User Voice [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/).